# Angular velocity of a body observed from a frame of reference fixed on the body

Tags: kinematics, reference-frames, education, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

I have a body and the reference frames, one is the inertial reference frame O-xyz, the other is a non inertial reference frame O'-x'y'z' fixed on the body.
The angular velocity vector of the body observed in the inertial reference frame is $\overrightarrow{\omega}_{Inertial}$.

Is the angular velocity vector $\overrightarrow{\omega}_{Non-Inertial}$ of the body observed in the non inertial reference frame equal to zero?
If I observe a point of the body when I am fixed on the body, I will see that point fixed, so it has not an angular velocity in the non inertial reference frame. Is this right?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: I think so. Since the definition for angular velocity is just $\vec{r} \times \vec{v}$, and $\vec{v}$ relative to that ref. point fixed on and coming with the body is just zero, no matter it is inertial or not.

Comment: Yes, it is zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are sitting **still** on a rotating merry-go-round / the Earth you are **not rotating** relative to the merry-go-round / the Earth.

Answer (score 1):

Your question, if taken literally, has an obvious answer, i.e. zero.
But this raised a doubt: perhaps you were thinking of a somewhat
different thing. In theory of rigid motions it's usual to refer the
angular velocity (wrt a "fixed" frame) to axes fixed to the body. At least in
italian tradition the angular velocity components referred to the
principal axes of inertia are called $p$, $q$, $r$.

Comment: Hello @ElioFabri, thank you for the clarification. I was confusing because in biomechanics we use a lot notations to specify each physical quantity, instead in mechanics books there is little care for the notations. Now I unsterstood the notations of the book